# How can I find which domain I'm on in Outlook 2007?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I'm trying to set up my PDA to link to the exchange server I'm on, and need to find which domain I'm connected to. Is there an easy way to do this in Outlook 2007?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to ask your IT dept to give you thid info but if you have Oulook setup with Oulook Anywhere it should show the address under Tools> Account Settings> Select your Exchange Server> More Settings> Connection Tab> Exchange Proxy Settings.

It's usually what Outlook Web Access address is, for example mail.domain.com.

Answer (score 0):

Under "Help" you should find "Client Email Settings".

However, it's entirely possible that your IT department has set up smartphone access to a different hostname, so if those settings don't work, you'll have to ask them, find some helpdesk-type documentation, or do some digging into the other registered DNS names to see if something sounds smartphone-ish.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on Tools tab and go to Account Settings to open your Account Info
2. Double click the email account that you want to look for in the list of accounts.

Take a look at this screen shot:
[image: account setting screen]